# Gatsbyjs image with Webp and fallback to jpg using picture tag not working

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm using Gatsbyjs image in my react website I tried adding fallback to jpg using the picture tag but its not working, it's just loading the jpg file here is the code

```
                     <Box {...portfolioImage}>
                        <picture>
                          <source
                            srcset={
                              (portfolioItem.image !== null) | undefined
                                ? portfolioItem.image.childImageSharp.fluid
                                : {}
                            }
                            type="image/webp"
                            alt={`PortfolioImage-${index + 1}`}
                          />
                          <Image
                            fluid={
                              (portfolioItem.imageFallback !== null) |
                              undefined
                                ? portfolioItem.imageFallback
                                    .childImageSharp.fluid
                                : {}
                            }
                            alt={`PortfolioImage-${index + 1}`}
                          />
                        </picture>
                      </Box>
```

The data

```
image {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(quality: 100) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
                }
              }
            }
            imageFallback {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(quality: 100) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                }
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Gatsby image is a component itself, not a data to be placed inside a `srcSet` attribute. In your case, you should render one component or another based on the `portfolioItem.image.childImageSharp.fluid` data, depending on if exist or not. In addition, those ternary conditions seem odd to me.

Assuming that your GraphQL queries work as expected and are retrieving the data. I would suggest simplier like:

```
{portfolioItem.imageFallback.childImageSharp.fluid
  ? <Image fluid={portfolioItem.imageFallback.childImageSharp.fluid} alt={`PortfolioImage-${index + 1}`} />
  : <picture><source srcSet={portfolioItem.imageFallback} alt={`PortfolioImage-${index + 1}`} /></picture>
}
```

With the snippet above you simply render the `<Image>` (from Gatsby image) if the data exist or the `<picture>` fallback image if not.

Wrapping the Gatsby Image inside a `<picture>` tag is not as useful as you may think since inside the image component will be a bunch of nested `<div>`s with the own JavaScripts fallbacks and blurs. This will change the default children of your `<picture>` tag causing potential issues or layout bugs.

---

> Check for data is not the point, I set the data I need to check if the
> browser supports webp image format which is what the picture tag is
> supposed to do but it seems not to be working with dynamic images or
> images that are loaded from JSON/grahql

Gatsby Image handles it automatically. From [their documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-image/#about-withwebp):

> If you want to automatically use [WebP images](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) when the browser supports
> the file format, use the `withWebp` fragments. If the browser doesn’t
> support WebP, `gatsby-image` will fall back to the default image format.

---

> need to test this again but pretty it did not work on safari

There's a known bug in Safari (or MacOS devices) with triggering of the intersection observer. To polyfill it:

```
yarn add intersection-observer
```

In your `gatsby-browser.js`:

```
export const onClientEntry = async () => {
  if (typeof IntersectionObserver === "undefined") {
    await import("intersection-observer");
    console.log("IntersectionObserver polyfilled ;)");
  }
};
```

Comment: Check for data is not the point, I set the data I need to check if the browser supports webp image format which is what the picture tag is supposed to do but it seems not to be working with dynamic images or images that are loaded from JSON/grahql

Comment: Gatsbi Image handles this automatically. You can check: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-image/#about-withwebp

Comment: need to test this again but pretty it did not work on safari

Comment: You can see here in the screenshot it does not work - https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbipylzqomvckea/Screen%20Shot%202020-09-21%20at%209.21.06%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Ok I was able to fix this I belive still testing